# Expand div container according to div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Just created a text slider with the div carrying the text expanding according to its content. The thing is that under this `div` is another div and when the text slider div expands it overlaps the div under it. Here is a brief description of the images.

Text slide goes on top of red div instead of red div going under

[image]

I need the red div to push down and pull up according to text slide content

Desired Result

[image]

```js
$(function () {

        setInterval ("slideImages()", 5000);

    });

    function slideImages () {
        var oCurImage = $("#slide div.current");
        var oNxtImage = oCurImage.next();

        if (oNxtImage.length == 0) {
            oNxtImage = $("#slide div:first-child");
        }

            oCurImage.fadeOut().removeClass('current');
            oNxtImage.fadeIn().addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
    }
```

```css
.news_others {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#slide {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
}
#slide div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
}
#slide div.current {
    z-index:1;
    display: initial;
}
#banner {
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    background: #dd0d0d;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news_others">
        <div id="slide">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Register as a Local buying agent if is want to buy goods available within your current locations. It's, easy
                    , safe, and reliable as we carry out background checks on importers we link you with.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam est turpis, fermentum vel leo quis, aliquam posuere ex.
                    Donec a efficitur augue, vel lobortis odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est. Proin id justo augue.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Register odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est. Proin id justo augue.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    If this works then yea its good. Because jnsalsa s laslknalsl alsnbasnlka slanlsnlka slk alnsklans
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Register as a Local buying agent if want to buy goods available within your current locations. It's, easy
                    , safe, and reliable as we carry out background checks on importers we link you with.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam est turpis, fermentum vel leo quis, aliquam posuere ex.
                    Donec a efficitur augue, vel lobortis odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est. Proin id justo augue.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work correctly.

```js
$(function() {
  slideImages()

  setInterval("slideImages()", 5000);

});

function slideImages() {
  var oCurImage = $("#slide div.current");
  var oNxtImage = oCurImage.next();

  if (oNxtImage.length == 0) {
    oNxtImage = $("#slide div:first-child");
  }

  oCurImage.fadeOut().removeClass('current');
  oNxtImage.fadeIn().addClass('current').animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.news_others {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#slide {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#slide div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
}

#slide div.current {
  z-index: 1;
  display: initial;
  background: #dd0d0d;
  ;
}


/* #banner {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        clear: both;
        background: #dd0d0d;
    } */
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news_others">
    <div id="slide">
        <div>
            <p>
                Register as a Local buying agent if is want to buy goods available within your current locations. It's,
                easy
                , safe, and reliable as we carry out background checks on importers we link you with.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam est turpis, fermentum vel leo quis, aliquam
                posuere ex.
                Donec a efficitur augue, vel lobortis odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est.
                Proin id justo augue.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                Register odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est. Proin id justo augue.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                If this works then yea its good. Because jnsalsa s laslknalsl alsnbasnlka slanlsnlka slk alnsklans
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                Register as a Local buying agent if want to buy goods available within your current locations. It's,
                easy
                , safe, and reliable as we carry out background checks on importers we link you with.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam est turpis, fermentum vel leo quis, aliquam
                posuere ex.
                Donec a efficitur augue, vel lobortis odio. Mauris est lectus, ornare ac justo eu, congue lacinia est.
                Proin id justo augue.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```